# Excel: Finding a value in a range of values

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup, range

In my Excel document, I have one sheet containing a column of important dates. In another sheet I have a list of all dates. I want to conditionally format that list such that if the date is present in the important dates column, it is highlighted.

What function should I use to determine if a value is present in a range of values? The LOOKUP, VLOOKUP, and HLOOKUP functions do not appear to do what I want.

Comment: Are you 100% you used all syntax options of LOOKUP and it's variants? Because what I typed in my answer is probably a "dumb" solution compared to using those functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the following conditional Formatting rule formula to your list of all dates:

```
=VLOOKUP(D1,A$1:A$5,1,FALSE)
```

Where "D1" is the cell-reference of the first cell in the all-dates range,
and "A$1:A$5" is the important-dates range (be sure to add the Workbook and Sheet references),

This assumes vertical lists of course.

Answer (score 1):

It might be your problem is not in the looking up, but in the [conditional formatting](http://excel.tips.net/Pages/T002664_Conditional_Formatting_Based_on_Date_Proximity.html):

> One important thing to bear in mind
>   with conditional formatting is that
>   criteria are evaluated in the order in
>   which they appear. Once a criteria has
>   been met, then the formatting is
>   applied and other criteria are not
>   tested. It is therefore important to
>   set out the tests in the correct
>   order. If, in the example above, the
>   criteria had been entered in the
>   reverse order, i.e. test for 14 days,
>   then 7 and then 0, it would have only
>   applied the 14 days format even if the
>   date entered was today. In other
>   words, if the date is today then all
>   three of the tests would have been met
>   so you have to be careful of the order
>   in order to get the result you need

---

And as an alternative to LOOKUP are you looking for something like this?

**[Date Intervals](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DateIntervals.htm)**

> This page describes a few methods for
>   working with intervals of dates.
>   Specifically, it address the questions
>   of whether a date falls within an
>   interval, the number of days that two
>   intervals overlap, and the how many
>   days are in one interval, excluding
>   those days in another interval.  These
>   formulas can be quite useful for
>   scheduling applications, such as
>   employee vacation schedules.
>
> Is A Date In An Interval?
>
> Suppose we have 3 dates -- a start
>   date, and end date, and a test date.
>   We can test whether the test date
>   falls within the interval between
>   start date and end date.   In this
>   formula, we will use three named
>   cells:  TDate1 for the start date,
>   TDate2 for the end date, and TDate for
>   the test date.  This formula will
>   return either TRUE or  FALSE,
>   indicating whether TDate falls in the
>   interval.
>
> ```
> =AND((TDate>=MIN(TDate1,TDate2)),TDate<=MAX(TDate1,TDate2))
> ```
>
> For example if  TDate1 is 1-Jan and
>   TDate2 is 31-Jan , and TDate is 15-Jan
>   , the formula will return TRUE,
>   indicating that  TDate falls in the
>   interval.
>
> In this formula, it does not matter
>   whether TDate1 is earlier or later
>   than TDate2.

Note: the page contains some more information on what to do, but I have a feeling you want something more dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the images as an answer, but it's faster for me:

[image]

[image]

Comment: And apparently, I can't tell when a question is nearly 3 months old.

Answer (score 0):

There are good free [Calender Templates available at **David Seah**'s site](http://davidseah.com/page/compact-calendar#downloads).
This has ZIP packs with XLS templates that use conditional formatting like you desire.

You might even consider using the templates directly...

Formatting sample,

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(D12,HolidayTable,2,FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE)
```

`D12` is the cell location on the formatted sheet.
`ISNA` checks if the `VLOOKUP` failed to locate the date.
The formatting is applied if match is confirmed (with a double negative check).

The *important dates* here are obviously the Holidays! `:-)`